# Explode and search-> mySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tag string saved as `$value` ,

`$value` is equal to `'my,name,is'` .

I now want to separate `$value` and search every row that contains (eg: 'name') in my db...

I've tried doing this ->

```
$value = explode(',' , $value);


$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE words LIKE '%$value%'    ";
```

But this doesnt seem to work..

Please help :)
Thanks a lot,

I will appreciate any answers...

Answer (score 0):

Need to Learn this by step by step

1)first get the full string in backend like "How to Work and Earn Money in expertsuggestion.com"

2)explode string by space

3)make a null array.

4)foreach for every explode string pass in you query one by one and the query of result array push into the null array

5)then after you can remove the duplicates id from array.

6)you got the final array.

Answer (score -1):

php explode() returns array.
So you will need to use $value[0] etc

or use foreach loop:

```
$value = explode(',' , $value);
$i = 0;
$len = count($value);
$q = ' ';
foreach ($value as $val) {
    $q .= 'words LIKE '.$val.' ';
    if ($i != $len - 1) {
        $q .= ' OR ';    
    }
    $i++;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$q'";
```

Did not test this, but you get the point. Comment if you need anything else.

Edit:

```
$value = 'name,is,my,etc';
$vals = explode(',', $value);

$i = 0;
$len = count($vals);

$string = '(';
foreach ($vals as $v) {
    $string .= "'".$v."'";
    if ($i != $len - 1) {
        $string .= ',';    
    }
    $i++;
}
$string .= ')';

echo $string;
```

This will echo: ('name','is','my','etc')
You can paste it here and see the results
http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Hi, I've tried this, but it doesn't work... 
After some testing I found  that  "SELECT ... words IN ( 'name', 'is' )" works  really well, but how can I break '$value' into this format -> ('name', 'is', 'my' )  ???

Answer (score -1):

Not possible as written. `$value` is going to be an array. When you use an array in string context, it becomes the literal text `Array`.

If you want to do a `like` on each individual member of that array, your query has to look like

```
SELECT ... WHERE words LIKE '%value1%' OR words LIKE '%value2' OR ....
```

That means exploding your string into an array, then wrapping each member of that array with the `'% ... %'` and `OR LIKE` business.

---

comment followup:

```
$parts = explode(',', $value);
$in_clause = "'" . implode("','", $parts) . "'";
$sql = "SELECT ... IN ($in_clause)";
```

but note that this leaves you open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: After some testing I found that "SELECT ... words IN ( 'name', 'is' )" works really well, but how can I break '$value' into this format -> ('name', 'is', 'my' ) ???